# How Android YouTube App Is playing videos in Pakistan?

Tags: youtube, android-youtube-api

YouTube is blocked in Pakistan almost 2 years ago, but it still displaying videos... But YouTube is not accessible through any Brower without any proxy or vpn software...
please tell me how Android youtube app works, ???

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on how the block is made.

If, say, they just restricted the access to "http://www.youtube.com", then the app may **dedicated endpoints** which go around their filtering.

Or again, if the block is made at IP level, the servers that hosts the APIs will have a **totally different set of IPs** than the website ones.

I'm just assuming, so don't take any of this for a fact.