# How is the YouTube Android app accessible while the website is banned?

Tags: youtube, ip, android-youtube-api, youtube-dl

I'm currently living in a country in which YouTube website is banned and you'll need a VPN or a proxy to be able to access the YouTube website and videos using a web browser, but surprisingly, I've found that sometimes (most of the times actually) I can access YouTube and watch YT videos without using any VPN or proxies by using the YouTube Android application on my phone/tablet. This is related to my ISP as far as I know.

How does the YouTube Android application can connect to YouTube servers without the need of any proxies or VPN while at the same time I have to use a proxy program like "Freegate" to be able to watch YouTube on my computer? Is there a trick to do on my computer to be able to watch YT in web browsers without using any proxies?

I used an app called "Packet Capture" which captured the following IP addresses:

```
74.125.173.200:443
216.58.208.42:443
172.217.22.34:443
173.194.188.70:443
```

When I type them into a web browser, they redirect to google.com.
Android Oreo 8.1.0 and the latest version of Youtube.

My main goal is to be able to use youtube-dl without any proxies.

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27792451/how-android-youtube-app-is-playing-videos-in-pakistan).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The censors can block in a number of ways:

1. By modifying the ISP's DNS server to make `youtube.com` resolve to an IP address of their own (or just `0.0.0.0`). Due to its minimal impact on the Internet infrastructure, this tends to be the preferred way in democratic countries. It can be easily evaded by using a DNS server not under the censor's control, e.g. `8.8.8.8` or `1.1.1.1`.
2. By blocking ranges of IP addresses, for example `172.217.0.0/16`. This is very likely to overblock, especially if the target is a smaller website which shares its IP range (or even IP address with others). Even in this case, outright blocking the whole /16 subnet would prevent access to google.com as well. This involves a lot of work on the censor's part, as IP addresses are routinely and automatically changed.
3. By reading traffic and blocking it if specific content is included. Since everything is encrypted these days, only DNS names and [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) are in the clear. There are already [ongoing works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_HTTPS) to close these loopholes. The downside for the censor is that they have to read and parse every single packet, i.e. need large equipment, although if restricting to only DNS it is far more feasible. This is also likely to introduce problems for unrelated services which may occasionally be misdiagnosed.

(There are a couple of other ways and finer distinctions I'm listing in my PhD thesis on the topic of censorship, but they don't apply here).

No matter which ways the censors choose, they must feed a list of forbidden items into their equipment. In case 1&3, that's domain names, in case 2, that's IP address (ranges).

Modern services like YouTube are internally split into multiple smaller services. For instance, YouTube may internally consist of:

- The web frontend, `youtube.com` / `172.217.22.46`
- The thumbnail service, `ytimg.l.google.com` / `172.217.21.206`
- The API `googlevideo.com` / `172.217.22.68`
- The video service, in multiple subdomains like `r3---sn-i5onxoxu-q0n.googlevideo.com` / `92.226.0.78`

All domain names and addresses are examples; in practice, every service uses many IP addresses and different domain names (for instance there's `www.youtube.co.uk` .

If the censors in your country block only web frontend, the Android app will continue to work. The censors may also forget some domains - i.e. block `youtube.com` and `youtube.pk` and their subdomains, but not `youtube.fr`.

Alternatively, the censors may have tried to block the Android app by IP address, but the IP address may have been changed by YouTube, either as part of automatic internal reassignment or by explicit censorship avoidance.

The Android app contacts the internal google API, since it wants machine-readable information. So why does youtube-dl use the web interface and not the Android API?

I can't speak for all developers, but as the long-time lead developer of youtube-dl I know why *I* mostly focused on the web interface: It was simply a matter of convenience, as the tools to debug and observe web applications are far better than those for Android (or iOS apps). Therefore, when I added features, I would observe how the web JavaScript app realizes them, and reimplement that in youtube-dl.

So far, mainly using the web API was sufficient, but you are very welcome to add alternative code that uses the calls the Android app makes. Beware that this relief may be temporary though, as the censors may notice that the YouTube app is unblocked, and update their domain name and IP range lists to include that service as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience in developing apps and programs. Is it relatively easy to make the necessary changes in the youtube-dl code to request YouTube content the way that the app does? Is there a guide on this? The problem with youtube-dl and using proxy software is that proxies are not reliable and can easily get disconnected.

Comment: With all due respect, but if you have no experience programming, you need to either learn it or hire somebody who has it, and [your question is off-topic here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The problem is less writing the actual code (which still will be a challenge for many junior developers), but more in reverse-engineering the requests the YouTube app makes. Somebody with expert-level skills in Android reverse engineering and networking could probably do it within a week. A junior developer would probably need a year or 2 just to learn the required techniques.

Comment: Also, I've found proxies and VPNs *very* stable. How come your  proxies get "disconnected"? Again, if you lack the necessary expertise to maintain a proxy or VPN, there are plenty of commercial offerings - [some](https://hide.me/en/) [even](https://www.tunnelbear.com/) [free](https://www.vpnhub.com/)!